# Spring AMQP Set prefetchCount on Queue Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

How do I set the `prefetchCount` on for this queue consumer?

```
@Bean
public Queue eventQueue(AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin) {
    Queue queue = QueueBuilder.durable(EVENT_QUEUE_NAME)
            ...
            .build();

    TopicExchange topicExchange = new TopicExchange(TOPIC_EXCHANGE, true, false);

    amqpAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder
            .bind(queue)
            .to(topicExchange)
            .with(EVENT_ROUTING_KEY));

    return queue;
}
```

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#containerAttributes) notes that `prefetchCount` this is a container configuration, but setting it on my factory bean did not work and the value defaulted to `250`:

```
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory containerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setPrefetchCount(10); // doesn't work; defaults to 250
        return factory;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Per @GaryRussell's comment below, I did test out the default `rabbitListenerContainerFactory` and also validated my Spring Boot configuration `spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.prefetch` was being consumed in `AbstractRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer`. However, when I look at the queue consumers in RabbitMQ, I can see that the queues that I define using the default container setup still have a `prefetchCount` of 250:

[image: rabbit admin shows consumer prefetch 250]

I'm using the RabbitMQ admin panel as the source of truth. I don't think it's lying, because I have a bunch of dynamic queues that are instantiated with custom containers, and those do have non-default (correct) `prefetchCount`s. I also validated in the Spring container startup that there was only the one (expected) `rabbitListenerContainerFactory` bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefetch is not a queue property, it's a consumer property.

What does your listener look like?

You are using a non-standard name for the container factory.

You either need to add `containerFactory` property to the `@RabbitListener` or you need to rename your bean to `rabbitListenerContainerFactory` (overriding Boot's defined factory `@Bean`).

Also

```
amqpAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder
```

You should not be talking to the broker in a bean definition - it's too early.

Simply add your queue, exchange, and binding as `@Bean`s and
You can also just set the prefetch in the application.properties/yaml file (if you are using Spring Boot). The admin will find them and declare them when the connection is first opened.

**EDIT**

There's someething else going on...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So62049769Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So62049769Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("so62049769");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so62049769")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.prefetch=42
```

[image]

Comment: You should not be talking to the broker in a bean definition - it's too early.

Comment: Updated comment after trying your suggestions (thank you). However, the default prefetchCount still seems to apply to any Queues declared via `@Configuration` + `@Bean`... other programmatic queues have the correct `prefetchCount`.

Comment: There's something else going on; see the edit to my answer; if you still can't figure it out; post a small verifiable example that exhibits this behavior, e.g. on GitHub.

Comment: Accepted answer. I was not using a `@RabbitListener` declaration; once I added that, I saw that I now had two consumers: one that had the correct `prefetchCount` (and was bound to the declared bean) and one that ultimately was configured with a `DirectMessageListenerContainer` (which was a later enhancement by our team that I didn't know about). The DMLC was easily configured by using the `spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.prefetch`.

Comment: If there was no `@RabbitListener` they must have configured a DMLC directly rather than via a factory.